# I have been trying to resolve Gradle error in flutter for some months. I will really appreciate if you guys can help out

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

OS:
Windows 10
Byte: 64 bit
HDD: 500 dedicated
8gb ram

Latest version of flutter as of April 2022.

Error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCG6O.jpg)